# What is the frequency with which partition offsets are queried by driver using the direct Kafka API in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Are the offsets queried for every batch interval or at a different frequency?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the term offsets, I'm assuming you're meaning the offset and not the actual message. Looking through documentation I was able to find two references to the direct approach.

The first one, from [Apache Spark Docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html#approach-2-direct-approach-no-receivers)

> Instead of using receivers to receive data, this approach periodically queries Kafka for the latest offsets in each topic+partition, and accordingly defines the offset ranges to process in each batch. When the jobs to process the data are launched, Kafka’s simple consumer API is used to read the defined ranges of offsets from Kafka (similar to read files from a file system).

This makes it seem like there are independent actions. Offsets are queried from Kafka, and then assigned to process in a specific batch. And querying offsets from Kafka can return offsets that cover multiple Spark batch jobs.

The second one, a [blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/03/30/improvements-to-kafka-integration-of-spark-streaming.html) from databricks

> Instead of receiving the data continuously using Receivers and storing it in a WAL, we simply decide at the beginning of every batch interval what is the range of offsets to consume. Later, when each batch’s jobs are executed, the data corresponding to the offset ranges is read from Kafka for processing (similar to how HDFS files are read).

This one makes it seem more like each batch interval itself fetches a range of offsets to consume. Then when running actually fetches those messages from Kafka.

I have never worked with Apache Spark, I mainly use Apache Storm + Kafka, but since the first doc suggests they can happen at different intervals I would assume they can happen at different intervals, and the blog post just doesn't mention it because it just doesn't get into the technical details.

Comment: Thanks for your research. I am looking for an exact answer, or a pointer to a piece of code that I can read to understand the coded behaviour.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope your expected answer shows up. I hadn't heard of the Direct Kafka API for Spark until I looked into this question.